# How to find intersection of two distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, intersection, probability-density

As the title, I am trying to find the intersection of two probability density function to locate the optimal decision point with minimum decision error.

In my case, 
One distribution is Rayleigh distribution and the other one is Rician 
distribution.

(you can think Rayleigh and Rician both as Gaussian distribution, because the problem I am trying to state would also occur in Gaussian case.)

To generate two vectors corresponding to each pdf.

```
Fs=1000;
x=linspace(0,20,Fs*20)
Ray=pdf('Rayleigh',x,1);
Ric=pdf('rician',x,3,1);
```

Intuitively, to find the intersection point of these two pdf.

I set a certain threshold, say

```
epsilon=0.001;
```

and traverse through all the vector elements of both vectors.

if the difference of elements bewteen two vectors are smaller than that threshold, then record the index.

if the intersection happens near

```
index=350,
```

then i can expect that the difference of value of these index

```
347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353,
```

will be smaller than epsilon
,then I choose the median , that is, index=350 ,to represent the intersection point of two distribution.

Now the problem is that because of the nature of these pdf, the value are both very close to zero in the very beginning and the tail.

So, no matter how I choose epsilon , the index that are recorded would be something like

```
1,2,347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 6000,6001,6002,6003,6004,6005,6006.....
```

How can I solve this problem? , or is there any robust way to find the intersection of two pdfs in Matlab? (I think this functionality should be quite fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your approach as follows:

- Use the pdf **ratio**, not difference. That way you avoid detecting the tails in addition to the intersection.
- **Minimize**, instead of appyling a threshold.
- **Vectorize**: compute the ratios for all points at once (and then minimize).

In other words:

```
[~, index] = min(abs(Ray./Ric-1));
```

In your example, this gives

```
>> index
index =
    2107
```

The pdf's as a function of *x* index are as follows. The found intesection index is seen to be correct (slightly above 2000 from the graph):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there must exist a minimum for the ratio at the intersection point, but I haven't figure out whether it would be a local minimum or a global minimum(It works robustly only if it is guaranteed a global min). Since view by the naked eye, it seems that there would be another minimum at the tails.

Comment: I've plot the abs(Ray./Ric-1), seems that the only minima is the intersection(and of course it's the global minima.) Thanks.

Comment: @AllenKuo Yes, the naked eye is misleading at the tails. Although it is not seen, one of the tails is many times greater than the other. In any case, you are right, my approach only works if there is only one local minimum. If there are several local minima, it will randomly produce one of them (which might not be the global minimum). For that case your threshold approach would be better